# Remove contents of directories without deleting contents

Tags: filesystem

What I am trying to do is remove only the folders that the files are contained within.

For example:

- Download
  -Folder1
  --File1
  -Folder2
  --File2

My goal is to remove Folder 1 and 2 and be left with the following:

- Download

-File1

-File2

Comment: you need to first move file1 and file1 into Download, and then delete folder1 and folder2

Comment: Yeah im not doing that 1000 times. Looking for an automatic method.

Comment: bash wildcards with mv and rm, I'm writing one for you now but that's the gist of it

Comment: @HelloMrMeseeks - put the detail from your comment in your question (ie that you need an automated process that will operate on 1000 directories).

Comment: This resembles a common homework problem. Lots of folks here are happy to help you learn, but wary of perhaps doing homework for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to first move (or copy) the files into the parent folder, and then delete the sub-folders. You could use the following commands from **inside the Download folder**:

```
mv */* .              # moves all items that are in folders to the current directory
rmdir */              # removes all empty directories from the current directory
```

From anywhere else in your system, just add the full path before the `*` and use the full path instead of `.`, for example

```
mv /home/hellomrmeseeks/Downloads/*/* /home/hellomrmeseeks/Downloads/
rmdir /home/hellomrmeseeks/Downloads/*/
```